# Unable to drag and drop marker on map using PIXI JS and Leaflet Mapping API

Tags: javascript, leaflet, pixi.js

I have loaded Markers Or Lat/Long Points on Map using [Leaflet.PixiOverlay](https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay)

Now I have two requirements

1. Drag and Drop an existing marker/point (PIXI.Sprite) on to the other marker/point
2. Drag and Drop an existing marker/point (PIXI.Sprite) to another location on map.

I have tried following approach but it is not working

```
/**
* In the below for loop identify the marker on which mouse down event has occurred. 
* In the 'mouseup' event on map, change the position of the selected marker
* 
* **Marker here is PIXI.Sprite**
*/
for (var i = 0; i < markersLength; i++) {
    var marker = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
    marker.interactive = true;
    marker.buttonMode = true;
    marker.on('mousedown', (event) => {
      self.map.dragging.disable();
      marker['dragging'] = true;
      self.selectedMarker = marker;
      console.log('event mousedown on marker ', event);
    });

    marker.on('mouseup', (event) => {
      marker['dragging'] = false;

      console.log('event mouseup on marker ', event);
    });
    marker.on('mouseupoutside', (event) => {
      //marker['dragging'] = false;
      console.log('event mouseupoutside on marker ', event);
      self.map.dragging.enable();
    })

    markerArr.push(marker);
    childContainer.addChild(marker);
}

/**
* mouseup event on map should move selected marker but it doesnot
*
*/

this.map.on('mouseup', (event) => {
  if (this.selectedMarker) {
    let markerCoords = this.latLngToLayerPoint(event.latlng, this.map.getZoom());
    this.selectedMarker.position.x = markerCoords.x;
    this.selectedMarker.position.y = markerCoords.y;
    this.selectedMarker = null;
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to drag or move the marker with mouse move I did following.

First created PIXI Overlay Layer

```
var pixiOverlayOptions = {
    doubleBuffering: /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window['MSStream'],
    autoPreventDefault: false,
}
var pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container();
pixiContainer.interactive = true;
pixiContainer.buttonMode = true;

var pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(function (utils, event) {
var zoom = utils.getMap().getZoom();
var container = utils.getContainer();
var renderer = utils.getRenderer();
var project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint;
var layerPointToLatLng = utils.layerPointToLatLng;
var getScale = utils.getScale;
var invScale = 1 / getScale();
var interaction = renderer.plugins.interaction;

switch (event.type) {
    // all other events
    ...
    case 'add':{
        var texture = resources['markerImage']
        var markerSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
        invScale = 1 / getScale(utils.getMap().getZoom());
        markerSprite.scale.set(invScale);
        markerSprite.on('mousedown', (event) => {
            this.mouseDownOnPoint(event, this);
        });
        container.addChild(markerSprite);
        renderer.render(container);
    }
        break;
    case 'pointDrag': {
       let latlng = event.latlng;
       let newCoords = project([latlng.lat, latlng.lng]);
       let marker = container.children[0];
       marker.x = newCoords.x;
       marker.y = newCoords.y;
       invScale = 1 / getScale(utils.getMap().getZoom());
        marker.scale.set(invScale); 
       renderer.render(container);
    }
      break;
  }
},pixiContainer, pixiOverlayOptions);

pixiOverlay.addTo(map);
```

Here few things are important

1. Marking Pixi Container with interactive as true and buttonMode as true
2. Adding autoPreventDefault as false in layer option object, which is passed to layer
3. Adding a 'mousedown' event handler, which actually marks the marker which is clicked.

Define function for handling 'mousedown' event on marker, see map dragging is disabled here

```
function mouseDownOnPoint(event, self) {
   self.map.dragging.disable();
   self.mouseDownOnSelectedMarker = event.currentTarget;
}
```

Define function for redrawing layer

```
function redraw(data: { type: PixiLayerEvents, [key: string]: any }) {
  pixiOverlay.redraw(data);
}
```

Add 'mousemove' handler on map, which actually calls redraw function with 'pointDrag' event

```
map.on('mousemove', (event: L.LeafletMouseEvent) => {
  if (this.mouseDownOnSelectedMarker) {
    this.redraw({ type: 'pointDrag', latlng: event.latlng });
  }
});
```

Inside 'pointDrag' event, marker position is continuously changed along with mouse move on map.

Once the 'mouseup' event occurs, just mark the 'mouseDownOnSelectedMarker' as null and enable map dragging

```
map.on('mouseup', (event: L.LeafletMouseEvent) => {
 if (this.mouseDownOnSelectedMarker) {
    this.mouseDownOnSelectedMarker = null;
 }
 map.dragging.enable();
})
```

[image]